# how to assign variable to min_score in elasticsearch and where can we implement logic for score?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to limit number of  documents based on score.how to assign variable to `min_score` in elasticsearch and where can we implement logic for score?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min_score` node to retrieve all documents having at least the minimum score specified.

Here is the JSON syntax:

```
"min_score": 0.5
```

Sample Query:

```
GET /_search
{
    "min_score": 0.5,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

[Reference link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html)

**Update**

To get top 80% documents with maximum score, first get the maximum score by fetching single best result. Below query will return single best result. Store `max_score` value from output.

```
GET /_search
{        
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    },
    "from" : 0,
    "size" : 1,
    "sort": [
                {
                    "_score": {
                        "order": "desc"
                    }
                }
            ]
}
```

Let's say we got `max_score` value in the response as `306.7351`. This value can be used as `min_score` to get top best results only.

```
GET /_search
{
    "min_score": 306.7351,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    },
    "from" : 0,
    "size" : 10,
    "sort": [
                {
                    "_score": {
                        "order": "desc"
                    }
                }
            ]
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes but it there a way for maximum score to filter documents?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Do you want to retrieve results having maximum score only?

Comment: I have 23 documents in an index. So i have to include in result the top 80% documents with highest scores. How can we do this?